# Grails render encodeAsJSON GORM with ObjectId (mongodb)

Tags: json, serialization, grails, mongodb

Here is a Model

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId

class Foo{  
 ObjectId id  
 String name 

}
```

And here an action

```
def action = {
 render(status:200, contentType:"application/json") {
    ['foo' : Foo.get(params.id)]
 }
}
```

The action will return something like this

```
{"foo":{"class":"Foo","id":{"class":"org.bson.types.ObjectId","inc":340737392,"machine":-2019394572,"new":false,"time":1299107672000},"name":"fooName"]}
```

My question is, how can I send in the json the toString of the ObjectId, I don't want this

```
"id":{"class":"org.bson.types.ObjectId","inc":340737392,"machine":-2019394572,"new":false,"time":1299107672000}
```

I want something more like

```
"id":18893828183
```

I know I can select the parameters I want like:

```
def foo = Foo.get(params.id)
['foo' : 'Foo' :[id:foo.id.toString(), name:foo.name]]
```

But I don't want to declare always what I want to return as json, I want to return all the object, Foo.get(params.id).encodeAsJSON()...

Is there a way to override encodeAsJSON()

I already tried to add this

```
class Foo{
 ....

 static transients : ['idStr']

 def getIdStr(){
     return this.id.toString()
 }
 ....
}
```

But it's ignored in the encodeAsJSON()

I even tried this

```
class Foo{
 ....
 def toJSON(){
        def obj =  this.encodeAsJSON() 
        def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(obj);
        json.idString = this.id.toString()
        return json.toString()
    }
...
}
```

this "works", but no....

because after this

```
 render(status:200, contentType:"application/json") {
    ['foo' : Foo.get(params.id).toJSON()]
 }
```

the render encode the json, so everything is "escaped"....

So what do you think is the solution, with a builder always defining what I want to return?

Hope, I made my question clear....

I'll start with the builder, hope you can give me another simpler / cleaner solution...

Thanks

*edit*
I just did a method that returns the object as a map so now I do something like this

```
render(status:200, contentType:"application/json") { 
   ['foo' : getFooAsMap(Foo.get(params.id))] 
}
```

Comment: I just did a method that returns the object as a map so now I do something like this
render(status:200, contentType:"application/json") {
    ['foo' : getFooAsMap(Foo.get(params.id))]
 }

Answer (score 4):

Register this objectMarshaller at Bootstarp.groovy and it will work like a charm

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.bson.types.ObjectId

JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(ObjectId) {
        return it.toStringMongod()
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me in Bootstrap.groovy in Grails 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be JSON-encoding your domain classes out to the web, I wonder if ObjectId might not be the best choice? The GORM/MongoDB integration allows you to use any type for the id. You could just declare it as a String type (which can be assigned as a toString of an ObjectId if you like to use that for its randomness) and then you don't need to worry about this mess. Any performance/scalability problems from this could be analysed/dealt with later, but I wouldn't expect there to be any unless it's a **very** large app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but I think, I'll stay with the ObjectId and a method that returns the object as a Map. In the page http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs (Object IDs are more synergistic with sharding and distribution)Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use GStrings in your map and you will get a numeric value for your ObjectId.
E.g.

```
render ["foo":"$foo.id"] as JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too:

```
def domainObj = YourDomainClass.get(params.id)

Map props = [:]
def domain = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(YourDomainClass.class)
domain.properties.each{
    props[it.name] = domainObj[it.name]
}

props["id"] = domainObj.id.toString()

render props as JSON
```

Or better yet, make it reusable. Put this closure someplace handy:

```
def mongoObjectResponse = {dobj ->

    Map props = [:]
    def domain = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(YourDomainClass.class)
    domain.properties.each{
        props[it.name] = dobj[it.name]
    }

    props["id"] = dobj.id.toString()

    // I like to leave room in my responses for messages and such
    message = ""
    obj = props
}
```

Then call like this from your controller:

```
return render(contentType: "text/json") {
    mongoObjectResponse.delegate = delegate
    mongoObjectResponse(domainObj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define your domain class as

```
class Foo {  
  String id  
  String name 

}
```

Instead of ObjectId